# How to declare events inside a dictionary initialization?

Tags: c#

I am creating a Dictionary of events and I want to declare those events inside the initialization of that dictionary instead of declaring them somewhere else and placing the links to the dictionary.

```
    static event EventDelegate Event1;
    static event EventDelegate Event2;
    static event EventDelegate Event3;

    public enum EventTypes
    {
        Event1, 
        Event2,
        Event3,
    }

    public static Dictionary<EventTypes, EventDelegate> events = new Dictionary<EventTypes, EventDelegate>
    {
        {EventTypes.Event1, Event1},
        {EventTypes.Event2, Event2},
        {EventTypes.Event3, Event3},
    };
```

So I want to do something like that:

```
{EventTypes.Event1, new event EventDelegate Event1}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Events (i.e., declared by using the `event` keyword) are type **members**. In the same manner as you cannot put/declare fields or properties themselves as dictionary values, you cannot put/declare events themselves as dictionary values What problem are you actually trying to solve with this approach? It smells rather like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What would be the purpose of that enum anyway? (What would be the benefit of writing/using `events[EventTypes.Event1].Invoke()` compared to using the event directly like `Event1.Invoke()`?)

Comment: What about something like `events.Add(EventTypes.Event1, (s, e) => Event1(s, e))` ?

Comment: I am trying to reduce the amount of duplicate code: as you can see, adding a new event takes 3 actions for me: the actual event declaration, the new enum item and the dictionary item, containing links to both.
And I need that dictionary to easily access static events from other classes by their type from the enum

Comment: You are not reducing the amount of code. _Why_ would you need the enum? You can easily access the events directly just fine without needing an enum (i mean, if you can easily access the enum from other classes, you can also as easily directly acess the events from other classes, which renders the enum as just being some redundant thing...) Avoiding the enum and the dictionary gets rid of that duplicate code.

Comment: @Nidere - Are you hoping to pass around the dictionary to allow code to subscribe to the events?

Comment: @Enigmativity sure, that's the point

Comment: @Nidere - If you're passing around events then using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx) - NuGet "System.Reactive" is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about wrapping the events?

```
class MyEventWrapper
{
    public event EventDelegate Handlers;

    public void Raise(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Handlers?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}

//

Dictionary<EventTypes, MyEventWrapper> eventMap = new Dictionary<EventTypes, MyEventWrapper>
{
    { EventTypes.Event1, new MyEventWrapper() },
    { EventTypes.Event2, new MyEventWrapper() },
};

//

eventMap[EventTypes.Event1].Handlers += (s, a) => { };
eventMap[EventTypes.Event2].Handlers += (s, a) => { };

//

eventMap[EventTypes.Event1].Raise(this, new EventArgs());
```

Comment: Not only have your solution solved the problem with declaring events, but it also allowed me to populate the dictionary with a single "foreach" loop through the enum.
So now I can create new events just by adding their name to the enum!
That's just fantastic, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you define your dictionary like this:

```
public delegate void EventDelegate(object data);

public static Dictionary<EventTypes, EventDelegate> Events =
    new Dictionary<EventTypes, EventDelegate>
    {
        { EventTypes.Event1, (EventDelegate)((_) => { }) },
        { EventTypes.Event2, (EventDelegate)((_) => { }) },
        { EventTypes.Event3, (EventDelegate)((_) => { }) },
    };

public enum EventTypes
{
    Event1,
    Event2,
    Event3,
}
```

Then this code works a treat:

```
Events[EventTypes.Event1] += (object data) => Console.WriteLine($"Event1 (1): {data}");
Events[EventTypes.Event1] += (object data) => Console.WriteLine($"Event1 (2): {data}");
Events[EventTypes.Event2] += (object data) => Console.WriteLine($"Event2: {data}");

Events[EventTypes.Event1]("A");
Events[EventTypes.Event2]("B");
Events[EventTypes.Event3]("C");
```

The output I get is:

```
Event1 (1): A
Event1 (2): A
Event2: B
```

You are then clearly declaring those events inside the initialization of the dictionary.